# How should I recover photos from an SD-Card?

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery, sd-card, testdisk

Using this SD card under Windows 10, I get a message that the SD-Card needs to be formatted and it says that its 0 B. I've tried every Windows 10 softwarebut nothing helped.

In UBUNTU:testdisk and photorec didn't work either and 
dmesg gave me:

```
[   89.909036] mmc0: card lacks mandatory SD Status function
[   89.909155] mmc0: new SD card at address 59b4
[  369.176583] mmc0: card 59b4 removed
[  375.135039] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 0001
[  375.135339] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 00000 7.61 GiB 
[  375.137132]  mmcblk0: p1
[  375.344887] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[  425.713091] mmc0: card 0001 removed
[  429.830068] mmc0: card lacks mandatory SD Status function
[  429.830183] mmc0: new SD card at address 59b4
[  537.945510] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  537.945514] usb 2-3.4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  556.372660] mmc0: card 59b4 removed
[  575.066545] mmc0: card lacks mandatory SD Status function
[  575.066664] mmc0: new SD card at address 59b4
```

Anyone any ideas???

Comment: "it says that its 0 B" Who says that? The output you posted says it's about 8GB large. Also, please provide the full `photorec` command you tried.

Comment: Hi. Thnx for caring. At the first part of my post I refer to what happen while trying under WIN10. A drive was recognized and when I hit properties of the drive, at my pc , I got that it was 0 B with free 0B. I've taken the SD to professionals and I'm waiting to hear the news... To see if the data can be recovered and what will the price be.

Comment: well, I suggest you make a copy of it using ddrescue and try working on that. Also, if you got error messages from TestDisk or Photorec we need to see them.

Comment: I just got news from the company guy .. He said that the controller is broken and that he has to get the memory chips out... The price is somewhere over 420€. I also made a call to another company and they told me 150-200€..

Comment: For hardware damage that's kinda the minimum you are going to spend.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the SD Card is just irreparably broken and *no software in the world will be able to repair broken hardware.*

**LQ Reviewers: That's it! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: Most likely, however the output shown in the Q shows 8GB, not 0b as stated in the text. This makes me wonder which one is accurate.

Comment: *Recupera*Bit will be no good, unfortunately, because most SD cards are not NTFS-formatted. But I am curious if OP can make a bitstream copy of the drive or not.